# Is there a way to set the initial count of an auto_increment field with phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I know in an actual query, you can use auto_increment=1 but how is this set with phpMyAdmin?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an excerpt on how to set a column to be auto incremented using phpMyAdmin:

> In the latest phpMyAdmin versions there is a new A_I Checkbox. Mark this option as enabled when creating or editing your primary key table column and that numeric field will automatically increment its value each time a new record is inserted.

And, to set the initial count to a specific value:

> Finally, if you want to change the current Auto Increment Value (i.e.: to make your auto increment field start from a specific numeric value) just select the phpMyAdmin Operations tab, type in the AUTO_INCREMENT field the new starting value of your auto incrementing field, and you are ready to go.

Taken from [**MySQL set auto_increment in phpMyAdmin**](http://trebleclick.blogspot.com/2009/01/mysql-set-auto-increment-in-phpmyadmin.html)

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find this anywhere.